# How to make it go back to the CLI after running cnetworkmanager?

Tags: debian, networkmanager

I am using Debian Squeeze on my laptop and installed `network-manager` with `cnetworkmanager` command line utility to handle my wireless connection. To get connected, I issue the command:

```
me@debian:~$ cnetworkmanager -C 'ESSID' --unprotected
Entering mainloop
(21:18:45) State: CONNECTING
(21:18:48) State: CONNECTED
```

And after that, it just stays there never going back to the CLI prompt. How do I run it so that after it gets connected, it will go back to the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a very basic level,

```
nohup cnetworkmanager -C 'ESSID' --unprotected &
```

but it might be worth thinking about writing it as a daemon, or a service of some kind if the tool doesn't already support it.

You could also run it in the foreground, then background it,

```
cnetworkmanager -C 'ESSID' --unprotected
```

Then hit `CTRL-Z` which drops you to the command line with the program 'stopped', at which point you background it using,

```
bg
```

The advantage being (over nohup) you can foreground it later using

```
fg
```

and interact with it.